# Entering data into Excel worksheets in an add in (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, worksheet

I'm creating an add in for Microsoft Excel that includes a ribbon tab.  On this tab is a button with the following code:

```
public void setAccounts()
{
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet displayWorksheet in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets)
    {
        displayWorksheet.Range[budget_cell].Value2 = "$" + Convert.ToString(budget);
        displayWorksheet.Range[account_cell].Value2 = "$0.00";
        displayWorksheet.Range[transaction_cell].Value2 = "Amount";
    }
}
```

The button opens up a separate form where the user specifies budget_cell, account_cell, and transaction_cell.  I then pass that data to the above code in SolutionName.ThisAddIn.cs (where SolutionName is the namespace of the solution).  Strictly speaking, the code works.  However, the data doesn't show up in the cells until the button is pressed a second time.  Why is that?  Is it because I'm retrieving the data from a different object in the solution?

Also, I've been trying to get this code and the aforementioned form to activate when the add in first starts up.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
    frmStartup startup = new frmStartup();
    startup.Show();

    setAccounts();
}
```

I've been at this for a good twelve hours now, and I can't get it to work.  What am I missing?

ThisAddIn.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;

namespace AccountingAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        public static string budget_cell = "";
        public static string account_cell = "";
        public static string transaction_cell = "";
        public static string date_cell = "";
        public static string time_cell = "";
        public static string description_cell = "";

        public static bool date = false;
        public static bool time = false;
        public static bool description = false;

        public static decimal budget = 0;

        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        public void budgetStartUp()
        {
            frmStartup startup = new frmStartup();
            startup.Show();

            setAccounts();
        }

        public void setAccounts()
        {
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet displayWorksheet in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets)
            {
                displayWorksheet.Range[budget_cell].Value2 = "$" + Convert.ToString(budget);
                displayWorksheet.Range[account_cell].Value2 = "$0.00";
                displayWorksheet.Range[transaction_cell].Value2 = "Amount";

                if (date == true)
                {
                    displayWorksheet.Range[date_cell].Value2 = "Date";
                }

                if (time == true)
                {
                    displayWorksheet.Range[time_cell].Value2 = "Time";
                }

                if (description == true)
                {
                    displayWorksheet.Range[description_cell].Value2 = "Description";
                }

                Account na = new Account(0, displayWorksheet);
                accounts.Add(na);
            }
        }

        protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(
                new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] { new MyRibbon() });
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {            
            CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject();
            budgetStartUp();
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }        
    }
}
```

frmStartup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AccountingAddIn
{
    public partial class frmStartup : Form
    {
        public frmStartup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a starting amount for your budget and " +
                            "which cells will display the running total for your " +
                            "accounts." +
                            "\n\nNote: Leaving the budget blank will" +
                            "      result in a starting budget of $0.00.");
        }

        private void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.budget += Convert.ToDecimal(txtStartingAmount.Text);
            AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.budget_cell = txtBudget.Text;
            AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.account_cell = txtAccount.Text;
            AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.transaction_cell = txtTransaction.Text;

            if (chkDate.Checked)
            {
                AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.date_cell = txtDate.Text;
                AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.date = true;
            }

            if (chkTime.Checked)
            {
                AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.time_cell = txtTime.Text;
                AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.time = true;
            }

            if (chkDescription.Checked)
            {
                AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.description_cell = txtDescription.Text;
                AccountingSeminar.ThisAddIn.description = true;
            }

            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your `budget_cell` declared? Where is your `setAccounts()`? What you're doing seems a bit twisted to me. I can't really reproduce your problem so can you provide more details so I am able to reproduce that error?

Comment: There you go.  That's the complete code.  Unfortunately, I can't show any screenshots of frmStartup.cs here.  All you need to know is that's where I have the user input the data I pass to ThisAddIn.cs.